# Xamarin - Two "Drawable" folders are getting displayed in droid project

Tags: xamarin-studio

I'm seeing two "Drawable" folder in droid project, one folder name is starting with CAPITAL "D" while the name of other is Starting from small letter "d".

This project is under source safe (SVN)

Any reason for this?[image]

Comment: (Assuming you are on OS-X) Check your `.csproj`, the odds are you have mixed-case resource paths, set them to match your physical directory naming case.

Comment: Thanks, it resolved the issue. I've edited the csProj file and removed the entry with "D"rawable and removed the folder too from Xamarin studio.